# Whether I can write the logic in View?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I can write myself's logic in the Serializer's create method:

```
class UserCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        username = validated_data["usernmae"]
        email = validated_data["email"]
        password = validated_data["password"]

        # there I can do myself's logic

        return validated_data
```

Whether I can write the logic in View? If is, how to do with that in View?

Comment: Be precise!! you can write your logic in view but what you want to do?

Comment: @Gahan I want to add custom information for the user which will be created. Such use the create time to generate a number for it.

Comment: you can do that in perform_create method or by overriding post method